# How can I break a `RemoveAll()`statement in C#

Tags: c#

I'm using the `RemoveAll()` statement, that do a foreach element of the list, and based in a condition returned by the delegate, it removes or not the element from the list. Like this:

```
x.RemoveAll(delegate(string y)
            {
               if (y == "abc")
                   return true;

               return false;
            });
```

I want to break the `foreach` from the removeAll, so that upon fulfilling some condition, I no longer even try to remove elements.  Something like this:

```
x.RemoveAll(delegate(string y)
            {
               if (Foo() || Bar())
                   break; //stop trying to remove elements

               if (y == "abc")
                   return true;

               return false;
            });
```

Have a way to do this without a auxiliary variable?

P.S: Using a auxiliary variable I know how to do.

Comment: Not really clear what you're trying to do...you want to return without returning true or false?

Comment: He wants to stop execution after a certain string was found.

Comment: I edited my question, the content of the string is not important.

Comment: wouldn't it just be better to use the foreach lamdba instead and just call remove manually?

Comment: `RemoveAll` just simply isn't going to let you exit early without using an auxiliary variable. If you want to avoid using auxiliary variables consider using LINQ instead of mutable lists

Comment: What should the effect of this `break` be - are all remaining items removed? Or preserved?

Comment: @johnny5 You cannot modify a collection whilst you are iterating it.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever the items removed continue removed. Only stop to don't check the next items.

Comment: @DanPantry :( with auxiliary variable  the code will be very ugly :(

Comment: @OnlyaCuriousMind You can encapsulate the logic into a separate method if it's something you find yourself needing to do regularly, which more or less removes that particular problem.

Comment: @OnlyaCuriousMind you can't really express 3 conditions (keep, remove, break) with single bool - so it makes what you are looking for painfully impossible. I posted sample code you are looking for as "comment" answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/31054434/477420, but really there is nothing wrong with extra variable as Servy pointed out in his good answer if you need to stick with updating existing Lists (and avoid `ToList()` calls required for LINQ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two real options.  A variable telling you not to remove more items:

```
var done = false;
list.RemoveAll(item => 
{
    if(done) return false;
    if(Foo() || Bar())
    {
        done = true;
        return false;
    }
    return item == "abc";
}
```

Or throwing an exception (despite the fact that it's really poor practice to use exceptions for control flow).

```
list.RemoveAll(item => 
{
    if(Foo() || Bar())
        throw new SomeTypeOfException()
    return item == "abc";
}
```

If Foo or Bar being true really are exceptional/error cases, then maybe you could justify it, but it certainly seems like code smell.  Note that this is technically going to be the *only* way to use `RemoveAll` and not actually invoke the delegate on any later items.

Fundamentally the problem is that the operation you're trying to perform isn't in line with what `RemoveAll` was designed to do.  What you really want is a version of the method that supports cancellation, or sufficient access to the internals of the list to create a comparable method with the appropriate cancellation.  Sadly, you don't have access to the underlying array in order to be able to replicate the ability of `RemoveAll` to remove multiple items without moving up all of the items until the very end, unless you re-create your own entire list based structure.

Answer (score 1):

Using simple loop with `break` will be way more efficient then using `DeleteAll` with trigger to generate false for all elements after a certain point.

Why not rather filter first:

```
foreach(var item in x.Where(o => Foo(o)).ToList())
    x.Remove(item);
```

If you care about efficiency, then

```
for(int i = 0; i++; i < x.Length)
    if(Foo(x[i]))
    {
        x.RemoveAt(i);
        break; // if list is sorted
    }
    else
        i++;
```

For unsorted list it's more optimal to go from top to bottom afaik.

Comment: This should work - note that `ToList()` is mandatory otherwise the lazy evaluation will bite you in the butt. However, OP only wants to remove the *first N* elements, so perhaps you should append a `.Take(N)` to the `.Where()` clause. The code is then reduced to `x.Where(o => Foo(o)).Take(N).Select((o) => x.Remove))`

Comment: You can't avoid copying in `foreach`. Most *efficient* solution is of course with indexes.

Comment: @DanPantry I should remove some elements, its can be 1 or N+1. Or all elements, or nothing Haha

Comment: @OnlyaCuriousMind sorry, I misunderstood your question

Comment: In which case, you could edit this code to `x.Where(o => Foo(o)).ToList().Select(x.Remove)` (although this will be deferred before being executed and is guaranteed to be O(N) + whatever the complexity of List.Remove is. This is why I suggested LINQ in the comments instead of using a mutable list)

Comment: Correct, but really bad solution - if you are removing more than one item complexity is O(list_count * remove_count) instead of O(list_count) due to very inefficient copying of the tail.

Comment: @Sinatr You can *absolutely* avoid copying the whole list.  It's not exactly *easy*, but it's absolutely *possible*.

Comment: @Servy, I am not copying *the whole list*. Or what do you mean?

Comment: @Sinatr with your first version of the code (`ToList()`), you are copying the whole list because you create a separate copy of the list with the `Where` clause in effect. If you didn't do this then you would be unable to iterate over the collection like you do.

Comment: You can avoid any copying of any collections, if you don't use the lists enumerator.

Comment: I am not copying the whole list, but a filtered copy. You can't avoid using copy (with iterator i mean) unless you start using indexes. Iterator always move to next, but with indexes you can *check* same index (after deleting item).

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with an extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> RemoveAllUntil<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> input, 
    Predicate<T> match, 
    Predicate<T> until)
{
    bool untilFound = false;

    foreach (T element in input)
    {
        if(!untilFound) untilFound = until(element);

        if(untilFound || !match(element))
        {
            yield return element;
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
var strings = new List<string> { "s1", "s2", "s2", "break", "s2", "s3"};
strings = strings.RemoveAllUntil(
        s => s == "s2", 
        s => s == "break")
    .ToList();
```

This will give you:

> s1, break, s2, s3

Answer (score 1):

Long comment: approximate code for removing item with cancellation and avoiding multiple copying of the tail:

```
void RemoveWithCancelation(this List<T> list, 
     Func<RemoveWithCancelationResult> predicate)
{
   var indexToKeep = -1;

   for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
   {
      var condition = predicate(list[i]);
      if (condition.Cancel)
          break;
      if (!condition.RemoveItem)
      {
          indexToKeep++;
          list[indexToKeep] = list[i];
      }   
   }
   if (indexToKeep+1 < list.Count)
       list.RemoveRange(indexToKeep+1, list.Count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done in the `RemoveAll()`.

However, you could 'simulate' the break with `TakeWhile()` and then filter the list with `Where()`

```
 var newList = x.TakeWhile(elem => elem != "your condition").Where(elem => elem == "abc");
```

Comment: What `RemoveAll` method you are using?

Comment: My bad, I didn't realized there is no `RemoveAll()` in `IEnumerable`. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score -1):

You could take advantage of closures:

```
bool stop = false; // the delegate closes over 'stop'
x.RemoveAll(delegate(string y)
{
   if (!stop && y == "abc")
       return true;
   if (Foo() || Bar())
       stop = true;
   return false;
});
```

Comment: *P.S: Using a auxiliary variable I know how to do*